# Is there any way by which I can `cache` the tabs selectively?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Is there any way by which I can `cache` the tabs in jQuery-UI selectively?

I mean , I have 3 tabs, and I want to `cache` only tab no. 2.

I know that we can use

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ cache: true });
```

But this caches all the tabs.

Thanks.

**Update**

I tried the suggestions by **voigtan** and **Pheonixblade9**, but it has same effect as that of

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ cache: true });
```

in short it is caching all the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can cache them by `id` by using

```
$("#tab1").tabs({cache:true});
```

Of course, you need to assign an id, but if there is logic to cache specific tabs, there should be logic to assign an id to each tab.

Comment: tried what you suggested, but it seems like it has the same effect as that of `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ cache: true });`, in short it is caching all the tabs :(

Comment: Are you assigning a unique id to each of the tabs?  That is, each of the divs representing a tab

Comment: As per this page: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs, I am not assigning any id to tab, since they will have auto-assigned ids. Hence I am doing this: `$("#ui-tabs-1").tabs({cache:true});`. I can also see the tab name in debugger.

Comment: Hmm, it may be that you can only set the entire tabset to cache.  That's what it looks like in the JQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able (if what @Pheonixblade9 says) is true:

```
$(".selector").each(function() {
    $(this).tabs({ cache: true });
});
```

should work also. or make your css-selector more uniqe like saying select only the first once or select all .selector but not the last one.

or:

```
$(".selector").tabs().eq(1).tabs( "option", "cache", true );
```

to set all .selector to tabs and filter out the 2:nd one and set its cache option to `true`. But I would go with a more specific CSS-selector(extra css-class saying it to cache or something).